# javascript - Why does this if statement not work?

Tags: javascript, html

I am testing a line of code where it checks a variable if it is empty or not. If its empty a prompt pops up. But even if the variable has something, the prompt still pops up.

```js
function myFunction(){
 
 if (site == null || variable == undefined) { 
  var site = prompt("Please enter a valid url:", "http://");
  document.cookie = 'Your bookmark is: '+ site;
  alert(unescape(document.cookie));
 document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = '<a class="txt2" href="' + site + '" target="myframe">'   + site + '</a>';
 }
 
 else { 
  alert('yey its working');
 }
}
```

```html
<a class="txt2" id="p1" onclick="myFunction()">Button</a>
```

The code works it's just after the variable is set the prompt pops up again before it loads the page.

Comment: Your `if` is testing two different variables. Where is `variable` declared? Anyway, `site` is declared locally inside the function, so it will be `undefined` at the point where the `if` condition is evaluated, and `==` considers `undefined` and `null` equal, so the `if` condition is always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because *variable* is undefined (we are not setting it anywhere), the if block always runs.

Also, if *site* variable seems defined in the scope of myFunction -

> Variables declared within a JavaScript function, become LOCAL to the
>   function

Ideal way is to check for document.cookie instead of variables -

```
    function myFunction(){

 if (  document.cookie == '') { 
  var site = prompt("Please enter a valid url:", "http://");
  document.cookie = 'Your bookmark is: '+ site;
  alert(unescape(document.cookie));
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = '<a class="txt2" href="' + site + '" target="myframe">'   + site + '</a>';
 }

 else { 
  alert('yey its working');
 }
}

myFunction();
```

Check it working in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b41epk4q/)

Comment: thanks that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement evaluates two variables which only either one has to be true in order for the if statement to be true.